# I want to get foreign key data from table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

[image]

I want to get data from table on the behalf of foreign key in a single view. I created a table which stores my headings and I created another table to store `sub_headings`. I created a relationship with foreign key. Know I want to get data from these tables. I already stored data in the database - how to retrieve it?

```
<div class=" col-md-4">
<div class="other-feature-item">
   This part I need from heading table
       <h4>heading</h4>

   This part I need from sub_heading table with above heading _id

   <ul style="list-style-type:circle;margin-left: 15px">
   <li>sub_heading1</li>
   <li>sub_heading2</li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For M-M relationship implementation, a Linking/Junction table should be used.

Check this site for sample and explanation:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/how-to-establish-relationship-between-tables-in-an-Asp-Net-w/

http://www.functionx.com/sqlserver/Lesson28.htm